# Cooks.distance function returning less values than the number of rows in dataset

Tags: r

I am doing logistics regression and want remove outliers with help of cooks d.So i was trying to cbind my dataset and cooks d values. 
i have removed missing values so thats not an issue.I dont have (x observation deleted due to missingness) line in my summary.
following is my code-

```
fit<-glm(CHURN~CHILDREN+CREDITA+CREDITAA+CREDITB+   CREDITC+CREDITDE+CREDITGY+  CREDITZ+PRIZMRUR+
       PRIZMUB+PRIZMTWN+REFURB+WEBCAP+TRUCK+RV+OCCPROF+OCCCLER+ OCCCRFT+OCCSTUD+OCCHMKR+
       OCCRET+  OCCSELF+OWNRENT+MARRYUN+MARRYYES+MARRYNO+   MAILORD+MAILRES+MAILFLAG+TRAVEL+PCOWN+
       CREDITCD+    NEWCELLY+NEWCELLN+INCMISS   +MCYCLE+SETPRCM + REVENUE   +MOU+RECCHRGE+
       DIRECTAS+OVERAGE+ROAM+CHANGEM+CHANGER+DROPVCE+BLCKVCE+   UNANSVCE+CUSTCARE+THREEWAY+
       MOUREC+OUTCALLS+INCALLS+PEAKVCE+OPEAKVCE+DROPBLK+    CALLFWDV+CALLWAIT+MONTHS+UNIQSUBS+
       ACTVSUBS+PHONES+MODELS+EQPDAYS+AGE1+AGE2+REFER+INCOME+   CREDITAD+SETPRC,data = mydata1,
     family = binomial(logit))
summary(fit)
cd <- cooks.distance(fit)
mydata2<-cbind(mydata1,cd)
```

i get the error-
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40000, 38941

My dataset(mydata1) has 40000 values and cd has 38941.
Why is it happening?

Comment: missing values, probably. Does `summary(fit)` say "1059 obervations removed due to missingness?"

Comment: No- this is the error-- Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40000, 38941

Answer (score 1):

Building on what JDL in comments suggested to you this is "probably" due to missing or inappropriate data.

To explain I have slightly altered the help example for the `cooks.distance` function by editing the `yi` variable to have a single NA value.

```
xi <- 1:5
yi <- c(0,2,14,19,NA)    # number of mice responding to dose xi
mi <- rep(40, 5)         # number of mice exposed
glmI <- glm(cbind(yi, mi -yi) ~ xi, family = binomial)
summary(glmI)
```

If you run this you can note that all the code still works.. However if you run the next line of that help example instead of getting 5 output values the same length as `xi` and `yi` you will get 4 due to the `NA` value in `yi`.

```
signif(cooks.distance(glmI), 3)
     1      2      3      4 
 0.311  0.258  1.430 13.100
```

You might possibly get similar problems if there are `Inf`s or other impossible values that "break" the `glm` fit. Note that if you look at `summary(glmI)` it contains the line:

```
 (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
```

Comment: I removed all missing values from my dataset and and I dont have this line-(1 observation deleted due to missingness) in my glm summary